# How should I check passwords in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am using Ruby to manage users in a database.

I am using `pass = Digest::MD5.hexdigest()` to encrypt passwords before they are being added to the database.

I need to create a function to check that a given password matches that stored in the database but I'm not sure how I should do it.

Do I use `pass = Digest::MD5.hexdigest()` on the user provided password, and then check that against what is returned from the database?

This is `correctpassword?`:

```
 def correctpassword?(nick, pass)
  user = nick
  pass = Digest::MD5.hexdigest(pass)

  db = SQLite3::Database.new "database.db"
  db.execute("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = ? and pass = ?", user, pass)

  !results.empty?
 end
```

This is attempting to use `correctpassword?`:

```
  if clt.registered?(@nick)
   if clt.correctpassword?(@nick, @pass)
    sv_send 'NOTICE', @nick, ":Correct password."
   else
    sv_send 'NOTICE', @nick, ":Incorrect password."
   end
  end
```

**I don't see either notices.** Using `correctpassword?` seems to break things.

This works though:

```
  if clt.registered?(@nick)
    sv_send 'NOTICE', @nick, ":This account is registered."
  end
```

Comment: Normally, you search for user and then you compare password. Also, adding salt to password improves security.

Comment: Because of the salt. So I should switch my sentences by place. :)

Comment: Why won't they match? I suppose they should match.

Comment: May be youd better use `Digest::MD5.hexdigest()` for generating and checking hash?

Comment: @sawa No idea. I updated the question.

Comment: What is the variable `l` supposed to be? You are taking `l[1]` as the user-entered password, so is it an Array? Or are you unintentionally taking the second character in a String as being the whole password here?

Comment: @SMW: The param name in your code, in the first line `def correct_password?(l)`

Comment: Huh? `def correctpassword?(nick, pass)`?

Comment: @SMW: You just edited that out whilst I was writing my comment - see http://stackoverflow.com/posts/29848096/revisions for revision history which clearly shows a different method signature that I was asking about!

Comment: Oh, before you commented yeah. I took some suggestions from the comments like switching to `Digest::MD5.hexdigest()`. Code still doesn't work in the current form above. `l` was a mistake earlier I guess.

Comment: There is no assignment for `results` var. Try `results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = ? and pass = ?", user, pass)`

Comment: @lx00st I have looked at this for hours. Oh no. Thanks. You should write it as an answer ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no assignment for results var. Do `results = db.execute("SELECT * FROM t1 WHERE user = ? and pass = ?", user, pass)`

Answer (score 0):

**MD5** is a `one-way` hash encryption algorithm. There is no way to directly decrypt a MD5 hash. The algorithm itself uses modular arithmetic to package the serialized string and there is no way to go backwards from that.

So I think you should convert the password to MD5 which user try to enter and compare that hash with stored encrypted password in db.

**Eg:**

```
 > stored_password_in_db = Digest::MD5.hexdigest('gagan')
 #=> "cc18a19beff0bdf874861a4dae6124b6" 
 > user_enter_password_for_login =  Digest::MD5.hexdigest('gagan')
 #=> "cc18a19beff0bdf874861a4dae6124b6" 
 > stored_password_in_db == user_enter_password_for_login
 #=> true 
 > user_enter_password_for_login =  Digest::MD5.hexdigest('Gagan')
 #=> "f52bb23033354697e8f55abdaed9d94f" 
 > stored_password_in_db == user_enter_password_for_login
 #=> false
```